# Placeholder position change to top of the input field

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to implement similiar feature in aura component as mentioned in the below URL:
https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/2/
But the problem is I am not able to use this css as mentioned here. what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible by directly adding this CSS in the Lightning Web Component CSS file, you need to create a static resource for css and load that in the LWC component and make sure to give a scope to the Lightning Web Component so that your component css doesn't affect other components UI.

1. Create static resource for CSS.
2. Load CSS resource in LWC component.
3. Wrap whole template content inside a div element and give it a class maybe *floatingLabel*

Make sure all css rules we have in static resource are using *floatingLabel* as parent.

Added css change and html structure changes in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/itzmukeshy7/buh6qfw7/.

Comment: can it be done by lightning aura components? no lwc

Comment: I never tried that, but I guess we can do that.